# CSS class reuse / auto populate

Tags: css, stylesheet

say I have a css class name

```
div.TestClass
{
     float:left;etc//
}

span.SpanTestClass
{
     float:right;etc//
}
```

on my form, I have got many spans and divs.

is there an easy way to implement all the classes for my spans and divs instead of typing them all out when I create a new span or div?
instead of this:

```
<span id=span1 class=SpanTestClass></span>
<span id=span2 class=SpanTestClass></span>
<span id=span3 class=SpanTestClass></span>
<span id=span4 class=SpanTestClass></span>
```

like so:

```
<div id="someDiv" class="someclass">
<span id=span1></span>
<span id=span2></span>
<span id=span3></span>
<span id=span4></span>
</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS

```
.someDiv{
color:#353535;
}

.someDiv span{
font-weight:bold;
color:red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="someDiv">

Hello <span>World!</span>

</div>
```

Any span tag inside a div using 'someDiv' as it's class will have red + bold text.

Comment: my question is, can I set the class instead of the css properties?
like inside .someDiv span{ class="ClassA" }

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to apply ids and classes from parent elements to child elements, which is what I think you're asking about. There's also no reason to need to.

HTML:

```
<div id="divid" class="divclass">
    <span class="otherclass"> ... </span>
    <span class="otherclass"> ... </span>
    <span> ... </span>
    <span> ... </span>
    <a href="#" class="otherclass"> ... </a>
</div>
```

If you want to target all elements in this specific div:

```
#divid * {
    ...
}
```

If you want to target all spans in this specific div:

```
#divid span {
    ...
}
```

If you want to target all elements in this specific div with a class of otherclass:

```
#divid .otherclass {
    ...
}
```

If you want to target only spans in this specific div with a class of otherclass:

```
#divid span.otherclass {
    ...
}
```

If you want to target all divs with divclass (instead of just the one with divid), simply replace `#divid` with `.divclass` in all of the above.

Comment: I think the last possibility is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can target the spans with

```
#someDiv span {
   //
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that with that rule, all `span`s in `someDiv` will take that style.